# Animate movement of arbitrarily positioned display:inline elements into a position:relative final position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML code consists of a div with spans of two types of classes: "hide" and "keep."

```
<div>
    <span class"hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span>
    <span class="keep">consectetur</span>
    <span class"hide"> adipisicing elit, sed do </span>
    <span class="keep">eiusmod</span>
</div>
```

JQuery code is in place that selects spans with class hide so that they may be faded out, leaving only the spans of class "keep" visible within the div.:

```
last.children("span.hide").fadeOut();
```

**Question**:  How can I animate the movement of the "keep" spans from their original positions in the text to their final ***visible*** positions?

The animation code is not a challenge to write so long as the initial and final position of each span can be identified.  The challenge(, I suspect,) is to determine the final position of each span once the "hide" class spans are hidden. Note that, despite my example code, there is an arbitrary number of "hide" and "keep" spans within the div, each with arbitrarily large contents.

*Note*: JQuery 1.6+ is used.

---

**Bonus Question**: How can I animate the movement of the "keep" spans *back* to their **original positions** after fading in the "hide" spans?

Comment: maybe you could use some tricks like stripping chars during the animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my raw, mostly untested thought:

1. Get the positions of the "keep" elements.
2. Hide the "hide" elements with `display: none`.
3. Get the new positions of the "keep" elements.
4. Show the "hide" elements again.
5. Hide the "hide" elements with `visibility: hidden` (so they retain their place in the layout)
6. Animate the positions of the "keep" elements relative to their normal position.

Because you do all of that without yielding, the user should just see the animation ([live example](http://jsbin.com/urepir)):

```
var hide, keep, deltas;

hide = $(".hide");
keep = $(".keep");

// Get current positions
deltas = [];
keep.each(function(index) {
  deltas[index] = $(this).offset();
});

// Hide and query new position
hide.hide();
keep.each(function(index) {
  var pos = $(this).offset();
  deltas[index].left -= pos.left;
  deltas[index].top  -= pos.top;
});

// Show again, hide whilst keeping space, then animate
hide.show().css("visibility", "hidden");
keep.each(function(index) {
  $(this).animate({
    left: -deltas[index].left,
    top:  -deltas[index].top
  });
});
```

That's completely un-optimised, and you probably want to do something when all the animations are complete, but it's a start and that live copy does actually work.

Re the bonus question: That part's easy, just `animate` back to `left: 0px` / `top: 0px`.

Here's a version with a toggle, and adding in the fades ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/urepir/2)):

```
var hide, keep, deltas;

// Get the spans
hide = $(".hide");
keep = $(".keep");

// Showing or hiding?
showing = !showing;
if (showing) {
  // Showing, this is easy
  hide.css("visibility", "").hide().fadeIn();
  keep.animate({
    left: 0,
    top:  0
  });
}
else {
  // Hiding -- get current positions
  deltas = [];
  keep.each(function(index) {
    deltas[index] = $(this).offset();
  });

  // Hide and query new position
  hide.hide();
  keep.each(function(index) {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    deltas[index].left -= pos.left;
    deltas[index].top  -= pos.top;
  });

  // Show again, hide whilst keeping space, then animate
  hide.show().fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).show().css("visibility", "hidden");
  });
  keep.each(function(index) {
    $(this).animate({
      left: -deltas[index].left,
      top:  -deltas[index].top
    });
  });
}
```

It's more fun with [more text](http://jsbin.com/urepir/3).

Comment: Wow.  I am genuinely impressed by the speed, quality, and volume of your answer.  I think I had the same "raw, untested thought" but you definitely followed through with it much farther than I did.  I voted you up and if your solution still stands a day (or two) from now I will accept it.  *[Applause!]*

Comment: @Time: :-) Glad I could help, have fun with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the best way would be to loop through each of the hide spans before hiding them and getting the next element (the "keep") element and storing it's position in a variable. Then you'd need to set it to position absolute with it's top and left position set to those you just got. At this point you would also need to get and store the position of the "hide" element too and animate the fadeOut and movement from the "keep" position to the "hide" position using the stored variables.

Answer (score 0):

Simple starting point. 
Add JqueryUI to get more effects

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span:last.hide").fadeOut(function(){
    $("span.keep").animate({paddingLeft:"+=5px",opacity:".5"});
  });
});
```

You can also give CSS3:transitions a go! Some amazing effects can be created like that